# Change bounding box dimension in Meshlab

Tags: bounding-box, meshlab

Please, does anyone know how to change the dimension of the bounding box in MeshLab? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hT6JW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

That bounding box should enclose only the vertices that are in your mesh. In this case it looks like you must have some vertices in the top left where it appears empty. Use the Select Faces Tool and select that region and press Shift-Delete which will delete faces and vertices. The bounding box should reduce.

Comment: I've tried this, using latest meshlab (2021.7) on a similar mesh, by selecting the main part of my mesh and then inverting the selection, and deleting faces and vertices. The bounding box remains the same.